# Hierarchical clustering on rows of varying length with sequence of numbers

Tags: r, hierarchical-clustering, unsupervised-learning

I want to do hierarchical clustering in one of my project.

My original problem is that I have a huge graph on which I have iterated large number of paths and reported nodes of path in below format. so each number in below sample represents a graph node and row represents a path. Now I want to cluster these paths on the basis of number of sharing nodes as a way to segregate similar kind of paths.

`1210, 158, 1222, 1468
1210, 1222, 198
158, 1468, 25, 26, 27, 28`

Now I want to do hierarchical clustering between rows based upon the number of similar nodes. In table above, rows(paths) 1 and 2 could be part of one cluster due to same nodes 1210 and 1222. Also rows(paths) 1 and 3 could be part of another cluster due to similar nodes 158 and 1468.

I checked that I can use `hclust` function to do hierarchical clustering.  This function takes dissimilarity matrix as argument. I am not sure how to create this distance metric. It seems that it could use Jaccard similarity measure. but I don't find any option in `dist` method for Jaccard similarity and and also for variable column format as above.

Regards,

Comment: Can I confirm that your data is basically an binary dataset, where each row represent an observation/sample, and each node numbers are variables present for that observation/sample?

Comment: each row represent a path of graph and numbers represent vertices in that path.

Comment: Yup, that's the description of the data. But given what you wanted to do, i.e. run a hierarchical cluster based on similar nodes, wouldn't it be easier to see the whole dataset as a binary dataset. You need a binary set to derive Jaccard distance anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of hclust with Jaccard distance (using vegdist in vegan package), based on abstraction of your data as a binary dataset:

```
dat
  25 26 27 28 158 198 1210 1222 1468
1  0  0  0  0   1   0    1    1    1
2  0  0  0  0   0   1    1    1    0
3  1  1  1  1   1   0    0    0    1

library(vegan)
dist<-vegdist(dat, method="jaccard")
hclust(dist) %>% plot
```

[image]

Comment: But my graph is huge, keeping such large number of columns is not possible.